# File manager for TinyMCE 5.0.6

Tags: javascript, tinymce, file-manager, tinymce-5

I have installed TinyMCE (TinyMCE Dev Package 5.0.6) in my personal project. Everything is installed and
configured correctly, but there is no File Manager available in this package. To resolve this flaw I have tried to install 
ResponsiveFileManager (RFM), but it just doesn't work. There is an error in a console when I click an icon of the RFM:

```
plugin.js:84 Uncaught TypeError: editor.windowManager.openUrl is not a function
    at Object.openmanager [as onAction] (plugin.js:84)
    at theme.js:21482
    at theme.js:9575
    at theme.js:21480
    at theme.js:2457
    at each (theme.js:267)
    at run (theme.js:2456)
    at theme.js:2969
    at theme.js:56
    at theme.js:10825
```

I guess that RFM is not properly prepared for this version of TinyMCE.

So I want to ask if there are any available file manager plugins for TinyMCE.
I need a file manager which is capable of:
- preview of uploaded photos,
- create new catalogs,
- upload files to server's catalogs (with Drag and Drop functionality as well).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using 5.0.6? `editor.windowManager.openUrl` was a new API in that release, so if you're using an earlier version it might cause that exception.

Comment: Yes. I use the latest version.

 https://pics.tinypic.pl/i/00984/1tc73hle69it.png

Comment: OK, must be a bug in the plugin then. You can open the console and `tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.openUrl` is a valid function.